# What does table.data refer to?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I did the [following W3C tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp) which helps to setup a basic MVC project including a SQL database. At that link you can see you have to replace `Site.css` with the shown CSS. This CSS includes the tag `table.data`, this does not seem to do anything however. I cannot seem to find anything about this `.data` tag and it seems all HTML tags I tried have this `.data` available.

So what is this .data actually referring too? And how should it be used to function with that tutorial?

Comment: css for any table with class name "data" ?

Comment: Ok lol, yes it is actually the class, I feel kinda stupid but this tutorial threw me off. The tutorial has a error in it since auto generating the views gives the class `table` to the actual table it is generating. But why does `.data` popup on every HTML tag I try? I guess somewhere there is a actual table with data defined as it's class? Using VS2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.data` refers to any table with the CSS class `data`.

For example:

```
<table class="data">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See the first entry in the [CSS Selectors Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

However, there doesn't appear to be a table with the CSS class `data` in that tutorial or the default MVC 3 template it is using. So, it doesn't appear to be correct. This won't cause an error, it just doesn't function.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out but this is the best answer. As for the side question, why does intellisense yield a `data` class for each HTML element I put a dot behind?

Comment: That is the Visual Studio Intellisense feature. It makes life easier by telling you all of the possible CSS class names that are available in the current application. It doesn't mean your table is referencing `data`, it is giving you the option to reference it if you need to (without having to refer to the CSS file to remember what the class name is).

Comment: Yeah, but nowhere data is declared as a class as far as I am aware of.